# Settting up logger to send emails to address different than admins

Tags: django, logging, django-1.8

In the settings file I have a logger set up to send any errors to `ADMINS` which is the default behavior. Here:

```
LOGGING = {
  'handlers': {'level': 'ERROR', 'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'}
  'loggers': {'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'], 'propagate': True}}
}
```

But I would like to set up a second logger to log a different type of errors and email should be sent to a different address.

I have my own logging function which writes to a file. Basically I want to send an email to that other address instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work or not. You probably may want to override Django '`AdminEmailHandler`' class.

Try overriding like this

```
from project import settings
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
from django.core.mail.message import  EmailMultiAlternatives

class CustomEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):

    def mail_extra_people(self, subject, message, fail_silently=False, connection=None,
                          html_message=None):
        """Sends a message to the extra people, as defined by the EXTRA_PEOPLE setting."""
        if not settings.EXTRA_PEOPLE:
            return
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            '%s%s' % (settings.EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX, subject), message,
            settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [a[1] for a in settings.EXTRA_PEOPLE],
            connection=connection,
        )
        if html_message:
            mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
        mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)

    def send_mail(self, subject, message, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mail_extra_people(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
```

And change your logging to

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'mail_extra_people': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'project.myutils.CustomEmailHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_extra_people'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

This should send mails to the mail ids that are mentioned in `EXTRA_PEOPLE` in project settings